# Why is Webpack build missing some third-party dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, code-splitting

Webpack appears to build my code successfully, but when I try to run the built app, I get the following error:

```
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Debugging indicates that there are a number of my dependencies from "node_modules" that are not listed in the `modules` map as expected.

In my case, the value of `moduleId` is `./node_modules/body-parser/index.js`, when the error is encountered, and I confirmed with debugging that this moduleId is not contained in `modules`. Therefore `modules[moduleId]` evaluates to `undefined`.

Can anyone explain why this is?

When I inspect `modules`, it contains other modules from `node_modules` and my own module files. Here is an sample of what `modules` contains:

```
{
'./node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/shared/App.less': function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) { … }
'./node_modules/express/lib sync recursive': function(module, exports) { … }
'./node_modules/mongoose/lib sync recursive':function(module, exports) { … }
'./node_modules/mongoose/lib sync recursive ^.*\/collection$': function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) { … }
'./node_modules/mongoose/lib sync recursive ^.*\/connection$': function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) { … }
'./node_modules/require_optional sync recursive': function(module, exports) { … }
'./src/server/index.ts': function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) { … }
'./src/shared/App.less': function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) { … }
'./src/shared/common/AdminUserMenu.tsx': function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) { … }
'./src/shared/common/Animated.tsx': function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) { … }
…
}
```

## UPDATE

Below is my webpack confirguration:

webpack.shared.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const LoadablePlugin = require('@loadable/webpack-plugin');

// https://developer.epages.com/blog/tech-stories/typescript-codesplitting-treeshaking/
const babelLoader = {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        // Leave es6 import/export statements alone so that WebpackConcat can do
        // tree shaking
        { modules: false }
      ],
      // Transpile TSX
      '@babel/preset-react'
    ],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
  }
};

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  // Shh
  // stats: 'minimal',
  // These are the types of files that webpack will be able to understand
  // syntatically. ".js" is required in order to parse third-party modules.
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.less', '.css'] },
  plugins: [
    new LoadablePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()
  ],
  stats: {
    // Examine stats for all modules
    maxModules: Infinity,
    // Display bailout reasons
    optimizationBailout: true
  },
  optimization: {
    mergeDuplicateChunks: true,
    flagIncludedChunks: true,
    // Figure out the order of modules that will result in the smallest initial
    // bundle
    occurrenceOrder: true,
    // Tell webpack to consider the 'sideEffects' flag in package.json
    sideEffects: true,
    providedExports: true,
    removeAvailableModules: true,
    // Tell webpack which exports are used in modules
    usedExports: true,
    concatenateModules: true,
    // Extract common dependency from the entry modules and place them into
    // their shared chunks
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Inline any SVG that is less than 1MB big
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: { limit: 1024 }
      },
      // Place all static resources referenced in code and markup into a folder
      // called 'static' and replace reference to locate them there
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: '/static',
          name: '[folder]/[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      // Compile Less (the loaders are run in reverse order)
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          // 3) Creates isomorphic style nodes from JS strings
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          // 2) Translates CSS into CommonJS
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              // The pattern with which our class names will be automatically generated
              localIdentName: '_[hash:base64:2]'
            }
          },
          // 1) Compiles Less to CSS
          'less-loader'
        ]
      },
      // Compile TypeScript
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [babelLoader, 'ts-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

webpack.server.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const sharedConfig = require('./webpack.shared.config');

module.exports = {
  ...sharedConfig,
  target: 'node',
  entry: { server: './src/server/index.ts' },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    filename: '[name].server.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.server.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/')
  }
};
```

Comment: can you share your webpack production config?

Comment: @KamranNazir, I've added them in an update to my question.